# Unable to mount free space on partition with gparted

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, mount, gparted

With gparted, I was able to create a set of free space that is ready to be made into a mountable drive, however mounting is not an option. Here are my options:

[image: gparted options]

When I right click, mounting is grayed out. I searched around and there seems to be very involved answers that would have me editing `/etc/fstab` and what-not... but I feel like there ought to be a way to make a partition and mount it through the GUI since it is such a basic activity.

Comment: Have you tried mounting your partition manually `sudo mount /dev/sda3 /media/mount_point`? I don't think you are able to mount with gparted (I have been wrong before though) Edit: It seems you can mount with gparted, you just need to have a corresponding entry in  `/etc/fstab` as you mentioned

Comment: Bingo! That worked. I must say, this was so trivial I wonder why gparted doesn't do this as well?